# Sorting a linked list in java which contains objects

Tags: java, linked-list

I have written the program as follows. I want to sort the linked list on basis of the String `a` in the class player.

now the output is

```
nagpur rathi
akola ashwin
```

but after sorting with the variable `a` it should be

```
akola ashwin
nagpur rathi
```

The code is as follows:

```
package link.demo;

public class Player
{
    String a,b;

    Player()
    {
    }

    Player(String city,String name)
    {
        a=city;
        b=name;
    }
}

package link.demo;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Linkdemo 
{
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
    {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Player b=new Player("nagpur","rathi");
        Player c=new Player("akola","ashwin");
        //player temp=new player();
        LinkedList<Player> l= new LinkedList<Player>();

        l.add(b);
        l.add(c);

        Iterator<Player> itr=l.iterator(); 

       while(itr.hasNext())
       {
           Player temp=itr.next();
           System.out.println(temp.a+" "+temp.b);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Collections.sort and override the compareTo method in the class to be sorted (player). This can probably easily be googled

Comment: Ok.
I will try to override the compareTo method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the player (data) class has to implements Comparable. As stated in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class
>   that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's
>   natural ordering, and the class's compareTo method is referred to as
>   its natural comparison method.
>
> Lists (and arrays) of objects that implement this interface can be
>   sorted automatically by Collections.sort (and Arrays.sort).

Therefore, after implementing this you can invoke `Collections.sort(l)`. I recommend reading http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/03/12/java_comp.html, that will teach you the basics.